# With tweepy how can you get favorites and retweets on a tweet?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have written this code that simply looks at the most 10 recent tweets about a certain query. I want to somehow get the number of favorites and retweets on it.

```
import tweepy
import time
import sys

consumer_key='…'
consumer_secret='…'

access_token='…'
access_token_secret='…'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

query="query"

non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

new_tweets = api.search(q=query,count=1)
for tweet in new_tweets:
   # Get favorites and retweets here

WOM=new_tweets[0].created_at-new_tweets[len(new_tweets)-1].created_at
```

Answer (score 3):

`tweet.favorite_count` and `tweet.retweet_count` is what you are looking for.

Comment: And if you're wondering how you can find out which specific users liked or RTed a tweet… you can't. The public API doesn't support that.

Comment: Only now I noticed the user could mean to get all RTs intead of number of RTs, thanks for completing my answer then!